# ERC20 token lost in the ether

Tags: contract-development, transactions, blockchain

Realise this is a long shot but giving it a go anyway: I had a situation quite recently where my wallet security was compromised and I suddenly had to move all of my crypto out of it quite quickly. In my haste I confused a contract address for my personal wallets address when sending a token across. I realise that these are 99.999% lost forever, but as I understand it from reading similar posts here, there may be the possibility that a function has been written into the contracts code to allow the transfer of tokens.

This is the contract where the tokens are stuck https://etherscan.io/address/0x9f599410d207f3d2828a8712e5e543ac2e040382

Please could anyone here have a look at the code to see whether such a function exists?

Much appreciate any help

Comment: I'm having issues with the ERC20 token also. Converted them a few times and nothing. It's still in my Trust wallet tho so not sure what's up

Comment: Sorry, but that contract doesn't have such functionality. The required function ".transfer" doesn't allow specifying an arbitrary address and the code doesn't have much upgradability, only a migrations agent that burn TTT tokens.